# Forcing dev-c++ to use c instead of c++

Tags: c, dev-c++

I am working with Dev-C++ because, it is very easy, but it always tries to compile code as C++ code instead of C code.

Can I force it to compile it as C code?

Comment: Save the code in a file with the extension `.c` instead of `.cpp` the IDE will then automatically compile it as C code.

Comment: What version of that IDE are you using? Does it  have something similar to this http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/introduction/devcpp/ ?

Answer (score 2):

Go to tools->Environment Options.

[image]

You will find the above dialog box. Uncheck the 
**Default to C++ on new project**
 option from the dialog box. This will probably solve your problem.

---

Another thing you should do to avoid dev c++ from compiling the code as C++ is **save your file as .c extension** and this will automatically make dev-C++ IDE to compile the file in C instead of C++.

Comment: When i compile, even with these settings. It encounters errors because of uncasted pointers and i have read that those errors only occurr when using C++

Comment: @BjörnMaxJakobsen while saving, have you tried saving your file as type - c source file? Also can you show the code that's giving error, so I may help further.

Comment: @BjörnMaxJakobsen You should show us sample code that fails in your question (i.e. edit your question and show what is not compiling).